# How do I install Davical?

Tags: postgresql

i'm using ubuntu 11.4 oneiric ocelot and tried to set up the Davical Server. I have installed it and added the users davical_app and davical_dba. A tutorial on http://wiki.davical.org/w/Ubuntu_Maverick
told me to say no to all three questions. Then it said to add the following lines to `/etc/postgresql/main/9.1/pg_hba.conf`:

```
local   davical_app     trust
local   davical_dba     trust
```

I tried to restart the postgresql server as the manual told me by the following init script:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

but this failed. The command told me that it couldn't load the pg_hba files because of line 77 and 78: the ones I've added. Then I restarted my computer because I thought then the postgresql server must restart too. I tried to run the shell script in

```
su postgres -c /usr/share/davical/dba/create-database.sh
```

anyway, but it said that it couldn't find the postgresqlserver.

On http://mergy.org/2011/11/fixing-davical-and-postgresql-on-ubuntu-11-10/ I found a tutorial to fix davical and postgresql 9.1 but that didn't help. What can I do to get it run on my Ubuntu system?

Comment: Is this still happening summerbrain or did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue relies on the pgsql listening on a unix socket located at /tmp/ while the davical script expects the unix socket to be in /var/run/postgresql/

I don't know how to change davical to look at the specified dir, but you can change the former in /etc/postgres/version/postgresql.conf, line unix_dir.